# Necessary condition for a $P$-matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I'm reading the following theorem from the book CONVEX STRUCTURES AND ECONOMIC THEORY by Hukukane Nikaido.

[image: I'm reading the following theorem from the book CONVEX STRUCTURES AND ECONOMIC THEORY by Hukukane Nikaido]

Here $P$-matrix refers to matrix whose principal minors are positive. I do not understand how such a  $y$ can be chosen. If $x_{k}$ is increased to $y_{k}$ so that $(Ay)_{k}=0$, then there is a change in other co-ordinates of $Ay$. It is possible that for some $i \neq k$, $(Ay)_{i}$ becomes positive. Then again we need to increase some other co-ordinate of $x$ to make $Ay \leq 0$. It seems to be a cyclic process. Can someone explain how to choose $y$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(Ay)_i$ became positive, it first became zero.  So just stop when it becomes zero instead of continuing further and trying to make $(Ay)_k$ zero.

In other words, take any nonzero $v \geq 0$ whatsoever, and let $y = x + t v$, where $t$ is the smallest value which makes some coordinate of $Ay$ zero.

Comment: I guess the positivity of the the diagonal entries are used to ensure that there is atleast one positive entry in each row so that we can make some co-ordinate of $Ay$ zero. Is that correct??

Comment: Yes -- what we need there is for the matrix to have at least one positive entry.

Comment: Suppose $A$ is a $P_{0}$ matrix.(i.e.det$A$>0 and all other principal minors are nonnegative). Is it still possible to say that $A$ has atleast one positive entry?!

Comment: But here determinant is not positive, its -1.

Comment: But why both $a_{ij}$ and $a_{ji}$ are zero, even if one of them is zero it will work right?!

Comment: True.  Maybe you should ask about the $P_0$ matrices in a separate question.